# Why ordinary sources of light such as bulb, flash light,.. etc cannot behave as coherent sources?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, coherence

A coherent source is a source which produces waves of constant frequency which does not change with time. In other words, it produces waves with constant phase difference which does not fluctuate. But my textbook says that ordinary sources of light are not coherent sources. But why? Here is the explanation from my textbook :

"In an ordinary source, light is emitted by atoms in discrete steps. An atom after emitting a short light pulse becomes inactive for some time. It again gains energy by some interaction, becomes active and emits another pulse of light. Thus, at a particular time a particular group of atoms is active and the rest are inactive. The active time is of the order of $10^{-8}s$ and during this period, a wavetrain of several meters is emitted.

We can picture the light coming from an ordinary source as a collection of several wavetrains, each several meters long and having no fixed phase relation with each other. Such a source is incoherent in itself. Different wavetrains are emitted by different groups of atoms and these groups act independently of each other, hence the phase varies randomly from train to train. If two lamps are substituted in place of the slits $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ in a Young's interference experiment, no fringe will be seen. This is because each source keeps on changing its phase randomly and hence, the phase difference between the two sources also changes randomly. That is why, a narrow aperture $S_{0}$, is used to select a particular wavetrain which is incident on the two slits together. This ensures that the initial phase difference of the wavelets originating from $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ does not change with time. When a new wavetrain is emitted by the lamp, the phase is randomly changed but that change is simultaneously communicated to both $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ the phase difference remains unchanged. In order to obtain a fairly distinct interference pattern, the path difference between the two waves originating from coherent sources should be kept small. This is so because the wavetrains are finite in length and hence with large difference in path, the waves do not overlap at the same instant in the same region of space. The second wavetrain arrives well after the first train has already passed and hence, no interference takes place. In practice, the path difference should not exceed a few centimeters to observe a good interference pattern.

Because of the incoherent nature of the basic process of light emission in ordinary sources, these sources cannot emit highly monochromatic light. A strictly monochromatic light, having a well-defined single frequency or wavelength, must be a sine wave which has an infinite extension. A wavetrain of finite length may be described by the superposition of a number of sine waves of different wavelengths. Thus, the light emitted by an ordinary source always has a spread in wavelength."

I did not understand the analogy of 'wavetrains'. Someone please explain why an ordinary source of light is incoherent in itself. I am so confused. Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is a filament lamp an incoherent light source?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/549965/)