# Why do light bulbs don't produce coherent waves?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, interference, coherence

My textbook says that light ways produced by light bulbs are not coherent but it doesn't describe the reason.

I was wondering how could two waves not be coherent regardless of the source they are produced from. As far as I know coherent waves are waves having a constant phase difference, meaning their phase difference remains the same with respect to time. If two waves are not coherent, does this mean their phase difference vary **as they are propagating?** If so, can you explain how is this possible and how does it happen if it does happen?

Comment: The relative phases between the various wavelets emitted from the source do not change as they propagate in a vacuum or homogeneous lossless medium. The lack of coherency in the context of a light bulb refers to the origination of these wavelets. Each wavelet is emitted from some molecular/atomic interaction at one time instant in one phase and one frequency is essentially unrelated to the other wavelets emitted at some other random time in some random phase and frequency, hence the sum total wave is incoherent "mess".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is a filament lamp an incoherent light source?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/549965/)